# Remove proxy server from command prompt

Tags: windows-10, powershell, proxy

I have set proxy server for my Internet browser. Now I need to disable it from PowerShell. How to achieve this? I run command below, but this not helped:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh winhttp reset proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy, just run these commands, you will need Administrator priviledges to do this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name ProxyEnable -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name ProxyServer -Type String -Value ""
```

Then the deed should be done.

---

Further reading: [Internet Settings registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/configure-client-proxy-server-settings-by-registry-file)